# OpenCV Line Segment Detector

Tags: python, opencv

According to the [LSD class reference](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d1/dbd/classcv_1_1line__descriptor_1_1LSDDetector.html#a2a4e6484d35ea1a16cd89cf06bab6aef), the default constructor is under `line_descriptor`. But a peek into the module reveals this as its contents.

```
# encoding: utf-8
# module cv2.line_descriptor
# from /Users/****/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
# by generator 1.144
# no doc
# no imports

# Variables with simple values

DrawLinesMatchesFlags_DEFAULT = 0

DrawLinesMatchesFlags_DRAW_OVER_OUTIMG = 1

DrawLinesMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_LINES = 2

DRAW_LINES_MATCHES_FLAGS_DEFAULT = 0

DRAW_LINES_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_OVER_OUTIMG = 1

DRAW_LINES_MATCHES_FLAGS_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_LINES = 2

# no functions
# no classes
```

A look into [xfeatures2d](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/df6/namespacecv_1_1xfeatures2d.html) bore no fruits as well.

According to [this](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/df/dfa/tutorial_line_descriptor_main.html) example though, the module does exist. Where can I find this module in Python?

*I am using OpenCV 3.2.0*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to OpenCv 3.0 doc it is

```
cv2.createLineSegmentDetector([_refine[, _scale[, _sigma_scale[, _quant[, _ang_th[, _log_eps[, _density_th[, _n_bins]]]]]]]]) → retval
```

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#createlinesegmentdetector

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A follow up question if you may. I'm trying to use their [createBinaryDescriptor](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/line_descriptor/doc/binary_descriptor.html?highlight=createbinarydescriptor) class along with the [keyline](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/dd7/structcv_1_1line__descriptor_1_1KeyLine.html) but I can't seem to find their Python equivalent. They just show the C++ version. Does this mean no Python APIs available? I really have tried searching around but they all seem to point back to the C++ versions even going back to version 3.0

Comment: I know that declaring, `lsd = cv2.createLineSegmentDetector()` makes `lsd` a binaryDetector. But what if I want to explicitly use their base binaryDetector class?

Comment: not sure, so just a guess: The binaryDetector might be just a virtual class without an implementation.

Comment: Any ideas on the [keyline](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/dd7/structcv_1_1line__descriptor_1_1KeyLine.html)? I really appreciate your help man. Seriously.